# Make complaint+ with

Tags: word-usage

Can we use **Make complain**t and **With** together?  For example is my following sentence correct :

**The land lord didn’t want to return my bond (even partially) till I made complaint with the tribunal which was very inconvenient for me.**

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is incorrect, strictly speaking, but it is not what a native English speaker would say. "Make complaint with" vaguely implies some sort of disagreement. Perhaps try "till I brought my complaint to the tribunal". Or, more informally, "till I complained to the tribunal". In both cases, "to" fits a little more naturally than "with". But again, I don't think that your original sentence breaks any rules. Hope that helps!